# Java Spark Dataset autogen compile exception

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm running into issues with Java Spark Dataset's groupByKey method. The following code, when run locally in a test environment (Spark 2.1.0, spark-core_2.11, spark-sql_2.11), throws the following exception:

`java.lang.Exception: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 43, Column 21: No applicable constructor/method found for zero actual parameters; candidates are: "public int org.package.example.ExampleTest$1ExampleClass.getX()`

Code is:

```
    class ExampleClass implements Serializable {
        private int x;
        private int y;
        public ExampleClass() {}
        public ExampleClass(int x, int y) {this.x = x; this.y = y;}

        public int getX() {return x;}

        public void setX(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

        public void setY(int y) {
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            ExampleClass that = (ExampleClass) o;

            if (x != that.x) return false;
            return y == that.y;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int result = x;
            result = 31 * result + y;
            return result;
        }
    }
    ExampleClass exampleClass1 = new ExampleClass(1, 1);
    ExampleClass exampleClass2 = new ExampleClass(1, 2);
    ExampleClass exampleClass3 = new ExampleClass(1, 3);

    List<ExampleClass> exampleClasses = Lists.newArrayList(
            exampleClass1,
            exampleClass2,
            exampleClass3
    );

    Dataset<ExampleClass> dataset = spark.createDataset(exampleClasses, Encoders.bean(ExampleClass.class));

    KeyValueGroupedDataset<Integer, ExampleClass> grouped = dataset.groupByKey(
            (MapFunction<ExampleClass, Integer>) ExampleClass::getX,
            Encoders.INT()
    );
}
```

It looks like it can't find the default parameter-less constructor, or I'm leaving something out. Also interesting, if I change the ints to boxed Integers, it says the candidate is getY() not getX().

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: After messing around with it some more, moving `ExampleClass` out of a nested class in my test and into its own file fixes the problem. I still don't know why though so any answers are still appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The problem in my case and I suspect in yours, is that your class isn't declared with the `public` modifier.

`public class ExampleClass implements Serializable`

Kudos to Andy Grove: https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg55084.html